# Kslice in brillioun zone

Tags: density-functional-theory, quantum-espresso, brillouin-zone, wannier90

Can anyone help me about the same issue.  How to find reduced coordinate of reciprocal lattice vector which defines kslice in brillioun zone?

Comment: Could you please reword your question? What do you mean by kslice?